# Is there an argument "speed" to run behaviorSpace experiments from the command line

Tags: netlogo

I would like to run behaviorSpace experiments from the command line. In the Netlogo interface, there is a slider "normal speed". By pressing this slider, it is possible to increase model speed. Is it possible to specify an argument "speed" in the command line to increase model speed ?

```
java -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp NetLogo.jar \
org.nlogo.headless.Main \
--model Test_model.nlogo \
--experiment experiment1 \
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, you're running the experiment in headless mode, so the speed slider can't help you, because the slider affects view updates only. In headless mode there are no view updates, so your model always runs as quickly as it can.